# Way to neatly represent array of objects with 2 values in JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, representation, data-representation

I have data in JSON format like this:

```
"members": [
            "admin@test.com",
            "user@test.com",
            "guest_test.com@##internalservicedomain.test.com##"
        ]
```

I want to add role so:

```
admin is administrator
user  is member
guest is guest
```

What is the best way to store it?

I can do it like this:

```
"members": [
                {name: "admin@test.com", role: "administrator"},
                {name: "user@test.com",  role: "member"},
                {name: "guest_test.com@##internalservicedomain.test.com##", role: "guest"}
            ]
```

Or like that:

```
"members": [
                "administrators": ["admin@test.com"],
                "users": ["user@test.com"],
                "guests: ["guest_test.com@##internalservicedomain.test.com##"]
            ]
```

But I don't like those solutions, is there a more neat way to represent it? I would prefer the first option, because then I can iterate more easily through the elements, but the overhead is terrible and the second option looks better, but seems complicated to iterate.

Comment: What language are you using to to read/write the data? In some 
languages, storing the 2nd option makes it really easy. i.e. foreach Member in Members ... type syntax is pretty clean. In JavaScript it'd be a little different, but I still vote for option number 2

Comment: We use Delphi's Object Pascal and some library for that. I think I need to write 2 foreachs to iterate the underlying array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more correct option in my opinion

```
"members": [
                {name: "admin@test.com", role: "administrator"},
                {name: "user@test.com",  role: "member"},
                {name: "guest_test.com@##internalservicedomain.test.com##", role: "guest"}
            ]
```

This way you can not only iterate better but if you add new roles in the future it will be much easier to accomodate.

Ultimately you can put role "A" for administrator, "M" for member and so on to cut some kbs...

Comment: Ok, I will use that even though I don't like it. I don't want to use acronyms for roles, because the system is huge and it would be unreadable for new programmers. I expected better answer, but it's probably my problem that I can't put a good question about the problem.